# z-index div keeps moving with change of screen size

Tags: css, z-index

I'm working on using UI from Figma to CSS for my react app. Currently, I'm trying to make 3 layers of div (className: 'a','b','c' respectively) in which they are on top of each other, div 'a' on the bottom, then 'b', then 'c' on top. All of them share one parent div.

Right now I didn't set div 'a'position, both 'b' and 'c' set to position 'absolute', z-index 1 and 2 respectively. It works fine except when I changed the screen size. Both div 'b' and 'c' started moving to the right as I widen the screen. I tried to change them to 'fixed' or 'relative' positions but didn't work either.
Below is my react component and css.

```
//react component

const Zoom = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BackgroundImage className='a' />
      <PromptBox className='b'/>
      
      <Link to="/zoom">
        <Button className='c' />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
//css 
 .a {
  width: 895px;
  height: 393px;
  left: 3px;
  top: 13px;
    }
.b {
position: absolute;
left: 25.56%;
right: 25.89%;
top: 8.15%;
bottom: 19.16%;
filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0.25));
   }
.c {
   cursor: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40.04%;
   right: 18.3%;
   top: 25.25%;
   bottom: 68.61%;
   }
```

Comment: See the following - `left: 50%, transform: translate(-50%)`: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#hv3

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want the moving divs to be?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), when you set `position: absolute;` "It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor". If no ancestor has a declared position then it uses the Window element, I believe. I think that's what is happening in your code.

Try adding `position: relative;` to the containing `<div>`. And note that because you did not set width and height values on 'b' and 'c', their size might be determined by the left/right/top/bottom values (depending on what other CSS you've added).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added relative position to the main div that holds these 3 divs, no change. I also changed the properties to height, width, left, top with px not percent, no change either.